# The gdb in NDK r7 maps code addresses to source code completely wrong

Tags: gdb, android-ndk

When I debug an app written in mostly native code (C++ and some C, multiple shared objects), that uses NativeActivity, ndk-gdb manages to set breakpoints in C++ functions just fine, but it maps code addresses to completely wrong source code locations. If I set a breakpoint at one C++ function that is in no way special except that its prototype is extern "C", "i b" shows the breakpoint being at /Users/tml/android-ndk-r7/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/include/exception:61 ... this makes single stepping through the function a bit silly, as gdb all the time thinks I am at line 61 in the exception header. What could be the problem?

Comment: Small correction: the function is not even 'extern "C"' but normal C++.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the solution suggested here (switch to stabs):

http://groups.google.com/group/android-ndk/browse_thread/thread/ebd969a055af3196